# Rselenium - "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74"

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando usar o `Rselenium`, mas parece que a versão do chromedriver foi atualizada e está retornando o seguinte erro:

> "Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 74
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

O código que eu utilizo é o seguinte:

```
webdrive = selenium(retcommand = T, verbose = T)
TerminalId = rstudioapi::terminalExecute(webdrive)
chrome = remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", port = 4567)
chrome$open()
```

Answer (score 2):

Caso alguém tenha interesse, resolvi o problema com o seguinte código:

```
webdrive = selenium(retcommand = T, verbose = T, chromever = "73.0.3683.68")
TerminalId = rstudioapi::terminalExecute(webdrive)
chrome = remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", port = 4567)
chrome$open()
```